# How HCE work with acr 122u nfc reader, When I am trying to work with below example code It is working like reader in android and ios

Tags: android, ios, nfc, hce, acr122

The code below is working when I emulate from android and iphone acts as a reader but not working with acr 122u usb nfc reader

Here I am posting the work around, any suggestions or source code would be really helpful.

*KHostApduService*

```
package com.example.testnfcsunday

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.nfc.NdefMessage
import android.nfc.NdefRecord
import android.nfc.cardemulation.HostApduService
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
import java.math.BigInteger
import java.util.*

class KHostApduService : HostApduService() {

    private val TAG = "HostApduService"

    private val APDU_SELECT = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xA4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
        0x04.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
        0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
        0x07.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
        0xD2.toByte(),
        0x76.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x00.toByte(),
        0x85.toByte(),
        0x01.toByte(),
        0x01.toByte(), // NDEF Tag Application name
        0x00.toByte()  // Le field  - Maximum number of bytes expected in the data field of the response to the command
    )

    private val CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xa4.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
        0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
        0x0c.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
        0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
        0xe1.toByte(), 0x03.toByte() // file identifier of the CC file
    )

    private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xb0.toByte(), // INS   - Instruction - Instruction code
        0x00.toByte(), // P1    - Parameter 1 - Instruction parameter 1
        0x00.toByte(), // P2    - Parameter 2 - Instruction parameter 2
        0x0f.toByte()  // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
    )

    // In the scenario that we have done a CC read, the same byte[] match
    // for ReadBinary would trigger and we don't want that in succession
    private var READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false

    private val READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), 0x11.toByte(), // CCLEN length of the CC file
        0x20.toByte(), // Mapping Version 2.0
        0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLe maximum
        0xFF.toByte(), 0xFF.toByte(), // MLc maximum
        0x04.toByte(), // T field of the NDEF File Control TLV
        0x06.toByte(), // L field of the NDEF File Control TLV
        0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte(), // File Identifier of NDEF file
        0xFF.toByte(), 0xFE.toByte(), // Maximum NDEF file size of 65534 bytes
        0x00.toByte(), // Read access without any security
        0xFF.toByte(), // Write access without any security
        0x90.toByte(), 0x00.toByte() // A_OKAY
    )

    private val NDEF_SELECT_OK = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // CLA   - Class - Class of instruction
        0xa4.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for Select command
        0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
        0x0c.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1), select by identifier
        0x02.toByte(), // Lc field  - Number of bytes present in the data field of the command
        0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte() // file identifier of the NDEF file retrieved from the CC file
    )

    private val NDEF_READ_BINARY = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
        0xb0.toByte() // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
    )

    private val NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN = byteArrayOf(
        0x00.toByte(), // Class byte (CLA)
        0xb0.toByte(), // Instruction byte (INS) for ReadBinary command
        0x00.toByte(), 0x00.toByte(), // Parameter byte (P1, P2), offset inside the CC file
        0x02.toByte()  // Le field
    )

    private val A_OKAY = byteArrayOf(
        0x90.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
        0x00.toByte()   // SW2  Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    )

    private val A_ERROR = byteArrayOf(
        0x6A.toByte(), // SW1   Status byte 1 - Command processing status
        0x82.toByte()   // SW2  Status byte 2 - Command processing qualifier
    )

    private val NDEF_ID = byteArrayOf(0xE1.toByte(), 0x04.toByte())

    private var NDEF_URI = NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en", "token", NDEF_ID))
    private var NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
    private var NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
        BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(), 2
    )


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        if (intent.hasExtra("ndefMessage")) {
            NDEF_URI =
                NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en",
                    intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage").toString(), NDEF_ID))

            NDEF_URI_BYTES = NDEF_URI.toByteArray()
            NDEF_URI_LEN = fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(
                BigInteger.valueOf(NDEF_URI_BYTES.size.toLong()).toByteArray(), 2
            )
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand() | NDEF" + NDEF_URI.toString())

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    override fun processCommandApdu(commandApdu: ByteArray, extras: Bundle?): ByteArray {

        //
        // The following flow is based on Appendix E "Example of Mapping Version 2.0 Command Flow"
        // in the NFC Forum specification
        //
        Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: " + commandApdu.toHex())

        //
        // First command: NDEF Tag Application select (Section 5.5.2 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(APDU_SELECT, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "APDU_SELECT triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        //
        // Second command: Capability Container select (Section 5.5.3 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        //
        // Third command: ReadBinary data from CC file (Section 5.5.4 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(
                READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER,
                commandApdu
            ) && !READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK
        ) {
            Log.i(
                TAG,
                "READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: " + READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE.toHex()
            )
            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = true
            return READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE
        }

        //
        // Fourth command: NDEF Select command (Section 5.5.5 in NFC Forum spec)
        //
        if (Arrays.equals(NDEF_SELECT_OK, commandApdu)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_SELECT_OK triggered. Our Response: " + A_OKAY.toHex())
            return A_OKAY
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN, commandApdu)) {
            // Build our response
            val response = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + A_OKAY.size)
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, response, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, NDEF_URI_LEN.size, A_OKAY.size)

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY_NLEN triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
            return response
        }

        if (Arrays.equals(commandApdu.sliceArray(0..1), NDEF_READ_BINARY)) {
            val offset = commandApdu.sliceArray(2..3).toHex().toInt(16)
            val length = commandApdu.sliceArray(4..4).toHex().toInt(16)

            val fullResponse = ByteArray(NDEF_URI_LEN.size + NDEF_URI_BYTES.size)
            System.arraycopy(NDEF_URI_LEN, 0, fullResponse, 0, NDEF_URI_LEN.size)
            System.arraycopy(
                NDEF_URI_BYTES,
                0,
                fullResponse,
                NDEF_URI_LEN.size,
                NDEF_URI_BYTES.size
            )

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Full data: " + fullResponse.toHex())
            Log.i(TAG, "READ_BINARY - OFFSET: " + offset + " - LEN: " + length)

            val slicedResponse = fullResponse.sliceArray(offset until fullResponse.size)

            // Build our response
            val realLength = if (slicedResponse.size <= length) slicedResponse.size else length
            val response = ByteArray(realLength + A_OKAY.size)

            System.arraycopy(slicedResponse, 0, response, 0, realLength)
            System.arraycopy(A_OKAY, 0, response, realLength, A_OKAY.size)

            Log.i(TAG, "NDEF_READ_BINARY triggered. Our Response: " + response.toHex())

            READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_CHECK = false
            return response
        }

        //
        // We're doing something outside our scope
        //
        Log.i(TAG, "processCommandApdu() | I don't know what's going on!!!")
        return A_ERROR
    }

    override fun onDeactivated(reason: Int) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDeactivated() Fired! Reason: $reason")
    }


    private val HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray()

    fun ByteArray.toHex(): String {
        val result = StringBuffer()

        forEach {
            val octet = it.toInt()
            val firstIndex = (octet and 0xF0).ushr(4)
            val secondIndex = octet and 0x0F
            result.append(HEX_CHARS[firstIndex])
            result.append(HEX_CHARS[secondIndex])
        }

        return result.toString()
    }

    fun createTextRecord(language: String, text: String, id: ByteArray): NdefRecord {
        val languageBytes: ByteArray
        val textBytes: ByteArray
        try {
            languageBytes = language.toByteArray(charset("US-ASCII"))
            textBytes = text.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            throw AssertionError(e)
        }

        val recordPayload = ByteArray(1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F) + textBytes.size)

        recordPayload[0] = (languageBytes.size and 0x03F).toByte()
        System.arraycopy(languageBytes, 0, recordPayload, 1, languageBytes.size and 0x03F)
        System.arraycopy(
            textBytes,
            0,
            recordPayload,
            1 + (languageBytes.size and 0x03F),
            textBytes.size
        )

        return NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, id, recordPayload)
    }

    fun fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(array: ByteArray, fixedSize: Int): ByteArray {
        if (array.size == fixedSize) {
            return array
        }

        val start = byteArrayOf(0x00.toByte())
        val filledArray = ByteArray(start.size + array.size)
        System.arraycopy(start, 0, filledArray, 0, start.size)
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, filledArray, start.size, array.size)
        return fillByteArrayToFixedDimension(filledArray, fixedSize)
    }
}
```

My *MainActivity* is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val nfcavailibility:TextView=findViewById(R.id.nfcavailibility)
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.hellobutton);
        val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        val nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(applicationContext)
        if (nfcAdapter != null && nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
           nfcavailibility.text="Avaliable"
        } else {
            nfcavailibility.text="Not avaliable or disabled"
        }
        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (editText.text.toString().length > 0) {
                val intent = Intent(this, KHostApduService::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("ndefMessage", editText.text.toString())
                startService(intent)
                showAlertDialog(editText.text.toString())
//                val nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, Intent(this, KHostApduService::class.java), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
//                intent.putExtra("ndefMessage", editText.text.toString())
//                if (nfcAdapter != null) {
//                    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, null, null)
//                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Enter tag no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        }
    }

    private fun showAlertDialog(toString: String) {
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
        alertDialog.setMessage("Emaulated Tag:-" + toString)
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(
            "Cancel"
        ) { _, _ ->
            val intent = Intent(this, KHostApduService::class.java)
            stopService(intent)
        }

        val alert: AlertDialog = alertDialog.create()
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

*apduservice.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name" android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">

    <aid-group android:description="@string/app_name2"  android:category="other" >
        <aid-filter android:name="D2760000850101"/>

</host-apdu-service>
```

Coming to my *AndroidManifest.xml* is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestNFCSunday"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".KHostApduService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">

            <!-- Intent filter indicating that we support card emulation. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Required XML configuration file, listing the AIDs that we are emulating cards
                 for. This defines what protocols our card emulation service supports. -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
                android:resource="@xml/apduservice"/>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Above is the code that I implemented and working as a NFC reader and it is not working with **acr 122u usb*** nfc reader

Comment: That is most probably due to the code driving the USB reader which you don't show.

Comment: @Andrew , hii, I have posted my completed code and I have connected NFC reader using USB to mac and NFC tools to view data